# Can one say "до следующего" or "до следующего раза" as a farewell?

Tags: приветствия

I seem to remember someone using this as a farewell, but when I search for the expression, it doesn't seem to be as common as I thought. Is it idiomatic to say something like "До следующего раза"? If so, can one leave out "раза"?

In French, for example, one can say, "À la prochaine", meaning "Until next [time]".

Comment: basically, one can say whatever he wants as a farewell. Some expressions are more common, other are more uncommon. This one is uncommon, I would say, but I wouldn't notice, if someone used it. That is, it is not something outright wrong, which reveals, that someone is not a native speaker or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't encountered its use in this sense.

Usually it's said when some business is left undone and is expected to be completed or resumed next time around.

What can be said though is **`до скорого!`** (equivalent of the German **`bis bald`**) which is a short form of **`до скорого свидания`** which in turn is a variant of the conventional **`до свидания`**, or the straightforward **`до встречи!`**

Still in modern language **`до скорого`** is not particularly colloquial. Sounds a bit pretentious to my taste.

Expecting to meet a person on a known day or at a known time of the day people might say **`до вечера!`**, **`до завтра!`**, **`до пятницы!`**, **`до следующей недели!`**.

Typically you would hear the unspecific in terms of time **`пока!`**, **`давай!`**, **`на связи!`** (keep in touch), **`до связи!`** (talk to you later), **`счастливо!`**, **`удачи!`**, **`увидимся!`** (see ya) and their combinations.

**`Пока!`** does have a connotation of `until`, etymology was discussed in Russian at ["Почему прощаются "пока"?"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)  and at ["Пока / Давай при прощании"](https://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/1136154.html)

Answer (score 4):

"До следующего" feels incomplete and wrong.

"До следующего раза" means not "until next time", but rather "until next occasion/event". As a farewell, it is OK to say to a person/a group of people who you meet only on some rare/specific occasions, according to some schedule, tradition, when the stars align, etc.

For example, you meet some people, say, once, twice a year for a party, a travel, something like that. When parting at the end of the event, because you don't expect to meet them until the next such event, you may say "ну, до следующего раза" (e. g. "until the next party/whatever").

Comment: I think the incomplete version _До следующего!_ can suit a specific situation, but it would most likely mean _'until next **one**'_, not 'next time'. An example (sorry, it's a bit ominous): a forensic officer and a coroner who know each other well, part using that phrase after delivering another dead body.